# Compare two Column and apply Jaro distance

Tags: python, jaro-winkler

I have a dataframe, I need to apply Jaro winkler distance, example - `jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(u'SHACKLEFORD', u'SHACKELFORD')`

dataframe -

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |
| value3 | value4 |

so basically I have two columns 'col1' & 'col2', I need to compare value1 with value 2 like -  `jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(u'value1', u'value2')` then value3 with value4 and so on, iteration should continue till last value and get the score in new column

expected output -

| col1 | col2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | 0.88 |
| value3 | value4 | 0.77 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['score'] = df.apply(lambda row : jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(row['col1'],
                     row['col2']), axis = 1)
```